# Illustrator CC live corners not all corners available to curve?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, pen-tool, anchor-point

[image: img]

This dot that appears at anchor points and you can drag to curve / arc the corner. This tool is useful but I want to know how to make it happen in the corners where it doesn't automatically appear?

Comment: The correct answer is that artwork must be larger than pixel-level to use Live Corners. Hopefully the question will be opened and answered correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called "Live Corners". This is a new feature to easily edit one or multiple corners at once.

**A common reason why the corner widget might disappear is that your artwork is too small.**

Working at sizes smaller than a single pixel can make live corners unavailable.

You can learn about Live Corners and see videos about it on Adobe's page: [Live Corners](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/illustrator-live-corners.html)

Here is the explanation from the related help document, [Live Corners From the Adobe Help Document](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/reshape-with-live-corners.html):

> You can select one or more corner anchor points in a simple path, or
>   multiple anchor points across several paths in your artwork. When
>   selected, a Live Corners widget appears next to each corner point.
>   Dragging a widget causes the corner point to change shape, into one of
>   three available corner types. The three available corner types are
>   Round, Inverted Round, and Chamfer.

**The Live Corners widget** (When it appears)

The Live Corners widget is enabled when:

- you select the Direct Selection tool (white arrow)
- you have a path selection containing corner points
- the artwork is sufficiently large (corner radii bigger than 1 pixel)

A Live Corners widget is displayed next to a corner when you select:

- One or more path(s) that have corners.
- One or more rounded corners